# Sending an email when meeting certain condition in Google Sheets App Script

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to set up an automatic email sending function to my inventory system. For example, when my current stock item goes below the threshold, it sends me an email. Column K consists of numbers of items, and Column J consists of predetermined threshold that we set. That being said, I only want to get a notification when Number in Column K < Number in Column J.

I tried multiple times, but I either gets tremendous trigger emails or none, case by case. Is there a way I can get a notification only when it meets the condition?

```
function request() {
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inStockRange = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Inventory").getRange("K2:K");
  var inStock = inStockRange.getValue();

  var minStockRange = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Inventory").getRange("J2:J");
  var minStock = minStockRange.getValue();

  if (inStock < minStock){
    var recipient = "myemail";
    var subject = "Inventory Update";
    var body = "Item from Inventory is below its minimum stock requirement.";
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to send one email per item? One email containing all the items below the threshold? or, A simple notification saying that at least one item is below the threshold?
 
Also, how often should the notification be sent?

Comment: Thank you, Bryan! I want to send one email containing all the items below the threshold. And, the frequency of sending a notification email is whenever the update in Sheets is about the current stock to go below threshold.

Comment: see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926379/in-google-apps-script-how-to-send-an-email-only-one-time-if-condition-met), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023795/sending-an-email-each-time-a-condition-is-met-from-a-spreadsheet-in-apps-script)

Comment: You mean, you want to trigger the `request` function whenever any cell in K = J (ie, K could be less anytime)? Or what do you mean by `whenever the update in Sheets is about the current stock to go below threshold`? Also, is this sheet updated manually or automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function inventoryUpdate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  const oA = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (Number(r[10]) < Number(r[9])) {
      oA.push(r.join(','));
    }
  });
  if (oA.length > 0) {
    let msg = `The following items are below minimum stock requirements.\n${oA.join('\n')}`
    MailApp.sendEmail("email address", "Inventory Update", msg);
  }
}
```

My Test Data was all numbers so it won't look like yours but here's what mine looked like.  I'm sure you can improve the looks and you probably won't want to use all of the items of each row.  But without additional information it's impossible for me to guess.

[image]